# How can I make it so my scale-transformed points don't get clipped in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a dotchart where I want to log transform the x scale. I have some points at 0, which ggplot handles nicely in that it doesn't eliminate them, however it does clip them.

What can I do so the points at 0 don't get clipped? It seems `xlim()` and the scale transformation don't play together, only the last one called takes effect.

An example:

```
myData <- data.frame(x = c(rexp(5), 0), y = "category")
myBreaks <- c(.1, 1, 5)
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log",
                   breaks = myBreaks,
                   labels = myBreaks) +
geom_point(size = 5, legend = F)
```

[image: clipped]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `log(0)` is `-Inf`, I suspect that your 0 point will always be clipped if you keep it zero.  I tried to fiddle with `expand=...`, `coord_trans` and everything else I could think of.

Here is a workaround:

- set your zero values to an arbitrary small value (say 1e-6)
- include a break at that value
- optionally label that break 0

The code:

```
myData <- data.frame(x = c(rexp(5), 0), y = "category")

myData <- within(myData, x[x==0] <- 1e-6)
myBreaks <- c(1e-6, 0.1, 1, 5)
myLabels <- c(0, myBreaks[-1])
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(size = 5, legend = F) +
    scale_x_continuous(
        trans = "log",
        breaks = myBreaks,
        labels = myLabels
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I thought it might come to that. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't accept this quickly. Hopefully @kohske will proves us wrong soon with an amazing tweak or a new geom!

Comment: @Kohske is unlikely to prove that log(0) != -Inf.  Anything else is misleading - especially labelling 10^-6 as 0!

Comment: Yeah, after trying a couple different "0" values I've decided to just omit the zeroes in my own data. Probably for the best. However, this answer still addresses the question well to keep them from getting clipped.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of ggplot2 version 3.0.0, you can use `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`.

```
library(ggplot2)

myData <- data.frame(x = c(rexp(5), 0), y = "category")
myBreaks <- c(.1, 1, 5)
ggplot(myData, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log",
                     breaks = myBreaks,
                     labels = myBreaks) +
  geom_point(size = 5, legend = F) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  labs(title = "coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')")
```

[image]